# docker: How to use shell variables in the shell entrypoint "sh -c"?

Tags: docker

I think I don't really understand how to use shell variables in the command parameter with the shell form. In my example the "echo" command show the correct string. I tried to transfer the variables content as $tps and /${tps} and ${tps} and just ${tps} or last but not least as "${tps}":

```shell
tps=$(</volume1/tps.txt)
echo "$tps"
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp  marctv/python-pymysql:latest sh -c 'python dwhproxy.py writemctps "${tps}"'
```

In any case the variable is not used as parameter in the python script. It seems to be empty or the variable **name** as a string. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used single quotes which prevent substitution. If you want substitution to occur in a string you must use double quotes:

```
docker ... "python ... ${tps}"
```

This is a property of all shells (at least, all shells I'm familiar with) and of many scripting languages with a similar heritage: one style of string is 'interpreted' and supports variable interpolation, escape codes, etc. and the other style does not (or supports a very much reduced set).

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much! I will accept this answer asap. You were to fast! =D